# "Add New" option in the select tag

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to "add new customer" option tag in the select tag. For example, there are 4 customer names in the select tag. Along with four customer names, they should be able to add more customers (c1, c2, c3, c4, Add New Customer)

On clicking "Add New Customer", it would open the modal where they can enter the customer name and save it

```
<select>
<option>C1</option>
<option>C2</option>
<option>C3</option>
<option>C4</option>
<option>Add New Customer</option>
</select>
```

I think this could be achieved with jQuery but don't know how to do it

Update:- Figured it out. I answered my own question! If you have a better approach to this method, then you are most welcome to answer the question

Comment: I have not voted this down, but it's going to get voted down, because you're expecting someone else to do the work for you, and have not provided evidence you've tried to solve this for yourself.

To answer your question, look up "select2" if you don't want to code something for yourself.

Comment: No, not at all. I'm not expecting someone else to do the work. I just need some guidance on it. Even theory would work! @SeanKendle

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just came up with one theory. What I can do is assign the id to the "add new" option tag and when someone clicked that option, it would open up the modal with the help of the jQuery click function. Is this the right approach? Just want to know if this is the right approach, the rest of job will be done by me @SeanKendle

Comment: 1) listen to change event 2) if it's last option (give it a `value=` so it's easier to identify) display a modal (pre-built or built dynamically, or just a `prompt()` to start with) 3) when modal closed, add option to `select`.  You'll probably want to persist it in a database on the server, so that would be 4) an ajax request *or* 5) a POST.   As you can see, there's quite a few non-trivial steps, so your question is too broad for SO.  You might like to concentrate on a specific part, try to get that to work, then ask a question regarding just that part.  Some people post follow-on questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this worked for me!

Select Tag

```
          <select class="form-control form-control-chosen" id="add-customer-tag">
          <option>Shakti Goyal</option>  
          <option>Nitin Goyal</option>
          <option value="add-new-customer">Add New Customer</option>
          </select>
```

Modal

```
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Name"> 
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code

```
$('#add-customer-tag').change(function() {
    var opval = $(this).val();
    if(opval=="add-new-customer"){
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
    }
});
```

Comment: In the future, including something like this in the original question will avoid being voted down. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Mistakes are part of the learning process @SeanKendle

Comment: No problem! That's why I didn't vote down, but wanted you to know why you were being voted down so you can learn and won't be frustrated with phantom down votes!